# Spring: 2 Repositories out of a single Entity

Tags: spring, spring-data

What I need is 2 Repositories created out of a single entity:

```
interface TopicRepository implements ReactiveCrudRepository<Topic, String>

interface BackupTopicRepository implements ReactiveCrudRepository<Topic, String>
```

How is that possible? Right now only one is created.

Comment: but why do you need two repository? what is the use case?

Comment: The backup holds a copy and the original can be updated but also reverted back to the backup one.

Comment: I believe you can do this. But the underlying datasource needs to be different

Comment: I am using MongoDB and Spring Boot 2.0 any easy way to do it?

Comment: If you are using  multiple mongo's then, Spring boot autoconfigure doesn't really help, You need to create multiple mongotemplates yourself and then bind these mongotemplates with repositories which you want to use. There is no easy way for this

Comment: ok thanks for the hint. i hope this does not end up in config hell :/

Comment: Not at all. I have applications connecting to 5 different mongos :)

Comment: Through the AbstractMongoConfiguration#mongoTemplate method? But how do I then connect these to my ReactiveCrudRepository so that I can let Spring create CRUD and some custom finders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do it.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb.topic")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "abc.def.repository.topic", mongoTemplateRef = "topicMongoTemplate")
@Setter
class TopicMongoConfig {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String database;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "topicMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate topicMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        final Mongo mongoClient = createMongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port));
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database);
    }

     private Mongo createMongoClient(ServerAddress serverAddress) {
        return new MongoClient(serverAddress);
    }
}
```

Another configuration

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb.backuptopic")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "abc.def.repository.backuptopic", mongoTemplateRef = "backupTopicMongoTemplate")
@Setter
class BackupTopicMongoConfig {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String database;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "backupTopicMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate backupTopicMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        final Mongo mongoClient = createMongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port));
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database);
    }

     private Mongo createMongoClient(ServerAddress serverAddress) {
        return new MongoClient(serverAddress);
    }
}
```

Your TopicRepository and BackuoTopicRepository should reside in abc.def.repository.topic and abc.def.repository.backuptopic respectively.

And also you need to have these properties defined in your properties or yml file

```
mongodb: 
   topic:
     host:
     database:
     port:
   backuptopic:
     host:
     database:
     port:
```

Lastly, disable springboot autoconfiguration for mongo.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help @pvpkiran.

Comment: Just a further question: With the above configuration is it still possible to have the 2 Interface Repositories in my initial post `TopicRepository implements ReactiveCrudRepository<Topic, String>` Or do I have to manually create all statements I need with the mongoTemplate?

Comment: Of course you can have repositories as before. only thing this configuration does is informing spring-data which mongoTemplate to use when you use a particular respository(This is done using this line `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "abc.def.repository.backuptopic", mongoTemplateRef = "backupTopicMongoTemplate")`). So we are telling spring, if I use any repository from `abc.def.repository.backuptopic` package, then use backupTopicMongoTemplate.

Comment: One more point to be noted is, you cannot have both the respositories in the same package. It has to be in different package. Or else whole thing goes for a toss :)

Comment: Thanks for your great effort! Cheers! :)

Comment: Im using properties files. Can you give the properties equivalent of the configs?