# Spring Boot multiple MongoDB configuration

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, configuration

I have looked everywhere for this and it seems like I cannot find a solution that works.  I am using spring boot 1.5.10-RELEASE.  I am trying to configure two different mongodb instances in the same application.  Here is my code:

Main Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.reef.reports")
public class MainApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

1st Instance

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.reef.repository.mongousa"} , mongoTemplateRef = "USAMongo")
public class MongoUsaConfig
{

    @Value("${usa.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${usa.mongodb.database:reef}")
    private String database;

    @Value("${usa.mongodb.port:27017}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${usa.mongodb.username:}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${usa.mongodb.password:}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${usa.mongodb.authdb:}")
    private String authdb;

    private final List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<ServerAddress>   hosts = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Method that creates MongoDbFactory
     * Common to both of the MongoDb connections
     */
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory()
    {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(getMongoClient(), database);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates MongoClient
     */
    @Bean(name = "USAClient")
    public MongoClient getMongoClient()
    {

        if ((null != username)&&(!username.isEmpty()))
        {
            hosts.add(new ServerAddress(host, port));
            credentials.add(MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(username, authdb, password.toCharArray()));
            return new MongoClient(hosts, credentials);
        }
        else
        {
            return new MongoClient(host, port);
        }
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "USAMongo")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate()
    {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }

}
```

2nd Instance

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.reef.repository.mongocan"} , mongoTemplateRef = "CANMongo")
public class MongoCanConfig
{

    @Value("${can.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${can.mongodb.database:reef}")
    private String database;

    @Value("${can.mongodb.port:27017}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${can.mongodb.username:}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${can.mongodb.password:}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${can.mongodb.authdb:}")
    private String authdb;

    private final List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<ServerAddress>   hosts = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Method that creates MongoDbFactory
     * Common to both of the MongoDb connections
     */
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory()
    {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(getMongoClient(), database);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates MongoClient
     */
    @Bean(name = "CANClient")
    public MongoClient getMongoClient()
    {

        if ((null != username)&&(!username.isEmpty()))
        {
            hosts.add(new ServerAddress(host, port));
            credentials.add(MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(username, authdb, password.toCharArray()));
            return new MongoClient(hosts, credentials);
        }
        else
        {
            return new MongoClient(host, port);
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "CANMongo")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate()
    {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it will run the configuration for the first instance.  However, it will not pick up the second instance.  I have put in breakpoints to debug and it never hits the breakpoint in the configuration.  The repositories in this package get loaded correctly:

```
com.reef.repository.mongousa
```

The errors happen with the repositories in this package:

```
com.reef.repository.mongocan
```

Please let me know what I am missing.  Why does one config work and the other does not?

Comment: check my answer here .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770121/spring-2-repositories-out-of-a-single-entity/48776527#48776527

Comment: I think I was missing the second excludes that you have.  I will try that an let you know how everything turns out.

Comment: Thanks for the help again.  One thing I found out is that the actual class/interface name has to be different as well as be in the different packages.  com.somepackage1.repository1.class will cause an error if the class name is com.somepackage2.repository1.class.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this blog post  https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

I tried it out for two MySQL DataBases and it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using two MongoDB instances and not using the JPA yet.  I will keep this post in mind when we move in that direction