# How to use multiple mongodb databases in spring boot application?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, configuration, application.properties

In my application, I need to use two MongoDB databases. I don't know how to add 2 MongoDB databases in the application.properties file in the spring application.

Here is the application.properties file of my project,

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=DB1
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=DB1
spring.data.mongodb.host=dev-ng-mongo1.domain.com
spring.data.mongodb.password=9876512
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 
spring.data.mongodb.username=pavan
```

but I want to use another MongoDB database for the same project. How can I add the new database in the application.properties file.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770121/spring-2-repositories-out-of-a-single-entity/48776527#48776527

Answer (score 26):

Please follow below steps to setup multiple mongodb data sources.

1. Define your primary and secondary mongodb properties like below in application.properties, please replace with them your db details:

   ```
   ######Primary Mongo DB########################
   spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
   spring.data.mongodb.database=primary
   spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
   spring.data.mongodb.password=*******
   spring.data.mongodb.username=*******

   ###########Secondary MongoDB#####################
   mongodb.host=localhost
   mongodb.port=27017
   mongodb.database=secondary
   mongodb.username=******
   mongodb.password=******
   ```
2. Now add Multiple Mongo Db Configuration..

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class MultipleMongoConfig {

   @Primary
   @Bean(name = "primary")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")
   public MongoProperties getPrimary() {
       return new MongoProperties();
   }

   @Bean(name = "secondary")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb")
   public MongoProperties getSecondary() {
       return new MongoProperties();
   }

   @Primary
   @Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate")
   public MongoTemplate primaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
       return new MongoTemplate(primaryFactory(getPrimary()));
   }

   @Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
   public MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
       return new MongoTemplate(secondaryFactory(getSecondary()));
   }

   @Bean
   @Primary
   public MongoDbFactory primaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
       return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
               mongo.getDatabase());
   }

   @Bean
   public MongoDbFactory secondaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
       return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
               mongo.getDatabase());
   }
   ```

   }
3. Now enable `EnableMongoRepositories` for your primary an secondary.please make sure you change `basePackages = "com.example.springbootmultipledatasource.primary.repository"` your repository package here

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = 
   "com.example.springbootmultipledatasource.primary.repository",
       mongoTemplateRef = "primaryMongoTemplate")
    public class PrimaryMongoConfig {

    }
   ```

Secondary Mongo Template:Please make sure you change your secondary repository package here `basePackages = "com.example.springbootmultipledatasource.secondary.repository`

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.springbootmultipledatasource.secondary.repository",
        mongoTemplateRef = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
   public class SecondaryMongoConfig {
   }
```

Now you can create your document, repository, service, controller and you are good to go.below is my project structure you can create or have different.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: How to achieve this on an LDAP secured MongoDB? The URI would change and SimpleMongoDB Factory fails.