# SpringBoot multipleRepositories <> multiple DBs cluster

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, multiple-instances

I've searched for Spring multi mongo config and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770121/spring-2-repositories-out-of-a-single-entity) helped me.

1. As an extenstion, I need help to configure cluster mongodb with different IP's. Here is my local sample.

How do I add multiple hosts here?

```
    mongodb:
  content:
    uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/contents
  genre:
    uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/genres
```

Updated config: Not working
// Tried similar to your answer also

```
mongodb:
  content:
    uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/contents,mongodb://un:pw@host1:27017/contents,mongodb://host2:27017/contents,mongodb://host3:27017/contents
  genre:
    uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/genres,mongodb://un:pw@host1:27017/genres,mongodb://host2:27017/genres,mongodb://host3:27017/genres
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain '/'
        at com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity(MongoNamespace.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:371) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.myplex.contentstore_v2.config.MongoContentConfig.mongo(MongoContentConfig.java:39) ~[classes!/:na]
        at com.myplex.contentstore_v2.config.MongoContentConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5039498.CGLIB$mongo$2(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
        at com.myplex.contentstore_v2.config.MongoContentConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5039498$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$434739cb.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at com.myplex.contentstore_v2.config.MongoContentConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5039498.mongo(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the servers of your cluster comma separated in the uri

```
uri: mongodb://username:password@server1:port,server2:port/database
```

Comment: I've tried this config style and is not working. Updated details in the question. Please observe I've tried uri similar to what's in answer and also added mongodb:// prefix. Both give same exception

Answer (score 0):

Other options you could have try loading different datasources(Mongo DB clusters) based on the app config setup.

Implement onReady @EventListener and load all the DB clusters at start the SpringBoot app.

Inside the onReady create all the datasources based on the config as below and store inside Map

```
HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("url", url);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("user", username);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
        com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

// Now lets store the hikariDataSource to a Map (dataSourcesMap)
try (Connection c = hikariDataSource.getConnection()) {
     dataSourcesMap.put(uniqueDBId, hikariDataSource);
}
```

I have successfully implemented this with Postgres and MySQL DBs in past in many SpringBoot application connecting with multiple DBs.

Answer (score 0):

For may be first timers adding more details

Official Doc: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/

Wrong:

```
 -     uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/contents,mongodb://un:pw@host1:27017/contents,mongodb://host2:27017/contents,mongodb://host3:27017/contents
```

Right:

```
 -     uri: mongodb://un:pw@primaryhost:27017/contents
```

I'm still analysing how it picks Replica set. But it worked for me.